# Can we overload operator<< with the first parameter being of the type std::ostream&& instead of std::ostream&

Tags: c++, function, overloading, iostream, ostream

I have learnt that we can overload `operator<<` as shown below :

```
class Person 
{
    public:
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Person& obj);
};
```

I absolutely understand the reason for the type of the parameters being reference. For example, the first parameter is a reference because streams can't be copied and the second parameter is a reference because we want to reflect the changes(if any as in case of `operator>>`) made to the original object. I know that since we have a low-level const in the second parameter its state can't be changed and by using reference we avoid copying.

My question is that can we( and should we) use rvalue reference instead of lvalue reference for the first parameter as shown below:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&& os, const Person& obj); //note the first parameter is rvalue-reference
```

Is there any reason why we should/shouldn't do what is shown above? More importantly, what will happen if we do so.

Similarly, my second question is that can we make the return type to be `std::ostream&&` instead of `std::ostream&`. In this case what will happen/change.

PS: I am learning C++ and have asked this question out of curiosity. That is, to deepen my knowledge of references and overloading.

Comment: If you used an rvalue reference instead of an lvalue reference, you woudn't be able to do `cout << person;`

Comment: @NathanOliver Ok can you explain in more detail as an answer why we wouldn't be able to do `cout << person;` then. I mean it may be obvious to you but for future readers and beginners like me, it is not. Thanks

Comment: Do you know what an lvalue and an rvalue is?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, they are value categories of expressions.

Comment: Okay, so lvalue references can only bind to lvalue expressions and rvalue expression can only bind to rvalue expressions.  In `cout << person;`, `cout` is an lvalue.

Comment: @Anya *My question is that can we( and should we) use rvalue reference instead of lvalue reference for the first parameter as shown below:* -- Did you try to compile such code?  It should take you a couple of minutes to see if your proposal actually is accepted by the compiler.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No i did not try to compile because in books i have seen that they just choose the first parameter to be a lvalue reference instead of rvalue reference. My current understanding is that, because we cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference that is why we don't have the first parameter as rvalue reference. Is this correct?

Comment: @NathanOliver My current understanding is that, because we cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference that is why we don't have the first parameter as rvalue reference. Is this correct?

Comment: @Anya *No i did not try to compile* -- Why not?  What good would a proposal be if it doesn't work at all?  That's the first thing you should have attempted, and then ask if it is possible.  The computer is not going to explode if the code doesn't compile.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie My question is not about whether the program works or not. Many program that have UB in C++, seems to work but they are actually in error. I am looking for the logical reasoning behind and not for can we make it work.

Comment: @anya Kind of.  Really, it comes down to rvalue references didn't exist before c++11, so before then the only solution was to use an lvalue reference.  Secondly, a temporary stream it something that isn't really used.  Normally you create a stream, write a bunch of stuff to it and then get rid of the stream when done,  Normally that means you want the stream to be around for more then a single line in the program.

Comment: @Anya [Doesn't take more than a minute](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e87dc85055ab09f).  What I am asking you to do is to see if the program *compiles*, not if it runs.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You're missing the point. I am not asking for verification by the compiler. I understand that many times the compiler will give us the hint about the problem(if any). And through that we can get an idea about what is going on. I am not looking for verfication. In this question, i asking why it is preferred the first parameter to be an lvalue reference instead of rvalue reference. That is i am looking for an **analytical  approach/explanation** rather than trial and error method.

Comment: @Anya -- The issue I have is that you didn't take the first step in trying to compile the code.  If you did that, then the question would be "Is it possible to have an rvalue reference as the first parameter.  I am getting a compiler error...", etc.  Or if it did compile and ran successfully, "I wrote this code using an rvalue reference, is this safe?".  I bet that others read your question, compiled the code, and may be basing some of their conclusions on that, which is perfectly valid to do.

Comment: Check out this one already in the standard [ostream.rvalue](http://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.rvalue)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I didn't take the first step because the first step IMO is to understand what is going on using first principles instead of just writing random code and expecting it to work. You're much more experienced than me in C++, and you may have different ways of analyzing a problem but i have just started learning C++ and want to know using reason what is happening in this case. Thanks for the input though, i will surely use it(your recommendation) in my future problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried writing something like the following, the program would not compile (this was already mentioned in the comments by @PaulMcKenzie):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

struct Person {
        int x = 0;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&& os, const Person& obj)
{
    return os << obj.x;
}

int main()
{
    Person p;
    std::cout << p;
}
```

You could however make the program compile by changing the last line in `main` into

```
std::move(std::cout) << p; // don't do this in real code
```

Then, the program would compile and output `0`. However the `std::cout` stream will be in a moved-from state after that and should not be used anymore.

Regarding some of the comments, there seems to be a misunderstanding about what a r-value reference is. Some seem to think it is just a *better* l-value reference, that we had no access to before C++11.

L-value references refer to something, that can be used on the left hand side of an expression. You can think of it as an reference to an actual object, that can be changed and assigned to and so forth. An r-value reference on the other hand refers to a temporary object, something, that can be used on the right hand side of an assignment.

Suppose you had two overloads of the `operator<<` with the following signature.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Person& obj);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&& os, const Person& obj);
```

The rules are, that the first accepts either a l-value or a r-value reference. The latter accepts only r-value references. If we call the operator with a l-value (`std::cout` is an example to this), the first overload will be used. If we call the operator with an r-value (like with `std::move(std::cout)`) the second will be used. You can omit the r-value reference overload, in wich case the first one is selected all the time, but you **cannot omit the first one if you want to call the operator with a l-value**. However calling the operator with an l-value is the thing you almost always want:

```
std::cout << p;  // will not compile if there is only an r-value reference overload
```

Now what are the use cases of r-value references? They are used to implement move semantics on objects. R-value references are used to refer to objects, that need no longer be valid after the current statement (they have no durability). While you can theoretically move the `std::cout` stream, just like shown above, this is not useful at all. Streams are meant to be used as objects with long livetime and not as temporaries.

So to finally **answer your question**: You should not do it, because streams are usually not used as temporary objects. If you really want to provide a r-value reference overload to the `<<` operator, go ahead, but **also provide a l-value overload** for the normal use case of `std::cout << p;`.

Comment: `std::cout` isn't moved-from in your example. You'd have to move `os` into a different `ostream` to break things.

Comment: Yes that's actually a good point. I am so used to think of `std::move`-ed objects as beeing invalidated, that I did not consider this ;) But nevertheless I would not recommend this style in real code.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that can we( and should we) use rvalue reference instead of lvalue reference for the first parameter as shown below:
>
> friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&& os, const Person& obj); //note the first parameter is rvalue-reference

This is technically possible (with some limitations) but is definitely very strange thing to do. Using rvalue reference usually implies the object will be “consumed” (e.g. moved-from) and shouldn’t be used in subsequent operations. But writing to a stream doesn’t consume it, generally; the stream is still available for subsequent writes.

Answer (score -1):

There are no technical reasons why you can't do either of those. However, if you do, you aren't interoperating with all the other things that define `ostream` operators.

If the input is `ostream &&` then you can't have an lvalue stream to the left

```
Person p;
std::cout << p // can't bind std::cout to ostream&&
```

It's bad manners to return an rvalue reference to something that you received by lvalue reference.

```
std::ostream&& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Person& obj) {
    // something involving obj
    return std::move(os); // stealing something that shouldn't be stolen!
}
```

If you want to have an expression with a temporary `ostream`, you can. The standard library [defines a template](http://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.rvalue) that takes an rvalue stream, applies the equivalent lvalue stream operation, and move-returns that stream.

Comment: I think you made a typo in the comment: *"// can't bind ostream&& to ostream&"* should rather be *"// can't bind ostream&& to oftream&"*  ?

Comment: @Anya no, the result of `std::fstream("person.txt") << p` is a `std::ostream &` bound to the  (temporary) `fstream`

Comment: Oh, ok due to **Derived to Base conversion** right?